# Simplest way to convert a string representing JSON array into Java array List of key value pairs

Tags: java, json, arraylist, hashmap

I have json string which looks like the following:

```
 "users":[
      {user_id=1,
       user_name=foo,
       profile_image=profile.png},
      {user_id=2,
       ............},
       .............
          ]
```

How can I convert it into a java arraylist of key,value pairs?

Comment: What have you tried and why is that too much code?

Comment: A `Map` of what? What is your desired result?

Comment: My question was unclear, I redefined it. Hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: @enu, What is an "arraylist of key,value pairs"?

Comment: it can be an arraylist containing Map objects for instance. Every Map consists of these keys (user_id, user_name, profile_image) and the corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String,Object> result =
    new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, HashMap.class);
```